# Skipping Strong Name Assembly for Windows 7 IIS 7.5 still give an error "Couldn't be Verified"

Tags: strongname

Environment Windows 7 IIS7.5 **64 bit**

I have an ASP.NET website traget framework 4.0 and I have a dll whose source code isn't with me and it's already a delayed signed assembly. Now I have added that assembly for skipping strong name verification using Sn -Vr *, Token. It got complied in VS2010 and If I press F5 it runs sucessfully. But I would need to add as a website under IIS to be used by other application as its a webservice. So when I am adding it as a website under IIS and running it shows the same error "Strong name signatuer could not be verified." but it's working from VS2010 instead but not from IIS why? 
I tried doing the same with a Windows 7 **32 bit** IIS 7.5 and is working, so it is some thing to do with 64 bit OS? Please help.